# How to use Oracle SDO_GEOMETRY in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to use `SDO_GEOMETRY` in my SpringBoot entity to store and retrieve `Polygon` data. Here's the field in my entity:

```
@Column(name = "shape",columnDefinition = "MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY")
private Polygon shape;
```

However, when I try to save the data, I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes:
expected MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY got BINARY
```

I'm using `hibernate-spatial` and my database is Oracle 19c. Here's the relevant dependency in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

my application.property:

```
# Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true

# Hibernate Spatial properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.spatial.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleSpatial10gDialect
```

and this is my service code:

```
    // set shape of range
    List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    for (RangeSpotsModel spot : rangeModel.getRangeSpotsModel()) {
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(spot.getLongitude(), spot.getLatitude()));
    }
    GeometryFactory geometry = new GeometryFactory();
    range.setShape(geometry.createPolygon(coordinates.toArray(new Coordinate[0])));

    range = rangeRepository.save(range);
```

this is full error:

```
message: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
stackTrace: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy251.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.sheikh.mems.range.business.service.RangeServiceImpl.create(RangeServiceImpl.java:91)
    at com.sheikh.mems.range.business.service.RangeServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$208728df.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.sheikh.mems.range.business.service.RangeServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b4e88a92.create(<generated>)
    at com.sheikh.mems.range.presentation.RangeControllerBackPanel.create(RangeControllerBackPanel.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3885)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy189.persist(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy189.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:666)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 111 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY got BINARY

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:630)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:564)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1151)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:771)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:299)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:498)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:152)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1052)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLStatement(OracleStatement.java:1531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1311)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3746)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3918)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3897)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:992)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Entity class seems to be correct but please verify one more time to check for any inconsistency if present.

**Note:** I guess you are creating and sending data in a wrong way to DB via controller. The controller logic looks suspicious. Please verify your controller and entity.

Also, check the DB Table. Drop the existing table and try to create a new table via Hibernate and verify once again.

---

Let me show how I tested to see it working. I started from the very beginning of setting up the Oracle DB on my system.

**Steps that will help you to reach to your solution:**

**Note:** I'm using **Oracle DB 23c**, **MacOS** & **JDK 17.0.8** to prove my point.

**You can use any version of Oracle DB.** For Windows, I guess Oracle DB installer is present. So, you can skip the VM based setup.

Oracle doesn't have installer support for MacOS. So, for that reason, I had to do in this way.

For MacOS way:

- Start with installing **Oracle Virtual Box** on the system. You can download from [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/technologies/download/) based on the OS.
- Then, download the installation **Oracle Database 23c Free - Developer Release VirtualBox Appliance (.vba)** from there official website [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/databaseappdev-vm.html).

  This `.vba` file provides pre-configured Oracle software for your use.

  The above virtual machine contains:

  ```
  1. Oracle Linux 8.7
  2. Oracle Database 23.2 Free - Developer Release for Linux x86-64
  3. Oracle REST Data Services 23.1
  4. Oracle SQLcl 23.1
  5. Oracle APEX 22.2
  ```
- You have to follow the setup video [here](https://youtu.be/ssef6bjPpZE) from Database Star will help you to setup.
- After, you done with this, install **Oracle SQL Developer** on to your system from [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/technologies/download/).
- Also start the VM containing Oracle DB hosted on linux. It will start the oracle DB as well.
- Start the Oracle SQL Developer and connect to the VM oracle DB and test the connection as successful or not.

[image]

For Oracle 23c, the default user - `hr` and password - `oracle` and pluggable db - `freepdb1`

You are done now with DB setup.

---

Now, coming to codebase:

I have created a sample spring boot project name 'demo' with this structure.

```
.
├── HELP.md
├── mvnw
├── mvnw.cmd
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── example
│   │   │           └── demo
│   │   │               ├── CustomConnectionFinderForSpatialSupport.java
│   │   │               ├── DemoApplication.java
│   │   │               ├── MyGeo.java
│   │   │               ├── MyGeoRepository.java
│   │   │               └── Resource.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── application.properties
│   │       ├── static
│   │       └── templates
```

**application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/freepdb1
spring.datasource.username=hr
spring.datasource.password=oracle
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.spatial.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleSpatial10gDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.spatial.connection_finder=com.example.demo.CustomConnectionFinderForSpatialSupport
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

**MyGeo.java:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Data;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon;

@Data
@Entity
public class MyGeo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "shape",columnDefinition = "MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY")
    private Polygon shape;
}
```

**MyGeoRepository.java**:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface MyGeoRepository extends JpaRepository<MyGeo, String> {

}
```

**CustomConnectionFinderForSpatialSupport.java:**

```
public class CustomConnectionFinderForSpatialSupport implements ConnectionFinder {
    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Connection find(Connection connection) {
        return ((HikariProxyConnection) connection).unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
    }
}
```

**Resource.java:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.io.ParseException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class Resource {

    @Autowired
    private MyGeoRepository myGeoRepository;

    @GetMapping("/save")
    public void save() {
        List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(0, 1));
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(2, 5));
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(2, 7));
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(0, 7));
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(0, 1));
        GeometryFactory geometry = new GeometryFactory();
        MyGeo geo = new MyGeo();
        geo.setId("ID");
        geo.setShape(geometry.createPolygon(coordinates.toArray(new Coordinate[0])));
        geo = myGeoRepository.save(geo);
        System.out.println(geo);
    }

}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.validation/jakarta.validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

As soon as I start the application, it will create the table 'MY_GEO' in the oracle db due to this property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`.

Click on refresh button in SQL Developer to bring the newly created table.

[image]

Table columns:

[image]

Now, I have an endpoint to save the data. So, as soon as I hit the url - `http://localhost:8080/save`

It successfully save the data without any issue.

**Spring Boot Console Logs (got the end of this log to see the printed data from that MyGeo Object):**

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:50764,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:/Users/anish/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.3/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/anish/Downloads/demo/target/classes:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/3.1.3/spring-boot-starter-web-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/3.1.3/spring-boot-starter-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.1.3/spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.1.3/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/3.1.3/spring-boot-starter-logging-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.4.11/logback-classic-1.4.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.4.11/logback-core-1.4.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.20.0/log4j-to-slf4j-2.20.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.20.0/log4j-api-2.20.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/2.0.7/jul-to-slf4j-2.0.7.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/2.1.1/jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.33/snakeyaml-1.33.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/3.1.3/spring-boot-starter-json-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.15.2/jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.15.2/jackson-annotations-2.15.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.15.2/jackson-core-2.15.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.15.2/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.15.2/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.15.2/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/3.1.3/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/10.1.12/tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/10.1.12/tomcat-embed-el-10.1.12.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/10.1.12/tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.12.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.0.11/spring-web-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/6.0.11/spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/6.0.11/spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.0.11/spring-context-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/6.0.11/spring-expression-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j/3.0.3/spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j-3.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter/4.0.4/spring-cloud-starter-4.0.4.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-context/4.0.4/spring-cloud-context-4.0.4.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/6.1.3/spring-security-crypto-6.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-commons/4.0.4/spring-cloud-commons-4.0.4.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-rsa/1.0.12.RELEASE/spring-security-rsa-1.0.12.RELEASE.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk18on/1.73/bcpkix-jdk18on-1.73.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk18on/1.73/bcprov-jdk18on-1.73.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcutil-jdk18on/1.73/bcutil-jdk18on-1.73.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-resilience4j/3.0.3/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-resilience4j-3.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-spring-boot3/2.0.2/resilience4j-spring-boot3-2.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-spring6/2.0.2/resilience4j-spring6-2.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-annotations/2.0.2/resilience4j-annotations-2.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-consumer/2.0.2/resilience4j-consumer-2.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-circularbuffer/2.0.2/resilience4j-circularbuffer-2.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-framework-common/2.0.2/resilience4j-framework-common-2.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-micrometer/2.0.2/resilience4j-micrometer-2.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-retry/2.0.2/resilience4j-retry-2.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-ratelimiter/2.0.2/resilience4j-ratelimiter-2.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-circuitbreaker/2.0.2/resilience4j-circuitbreaker-2.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-core/2.0.2/resilience4j-core-2.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.7/slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-timelimiter/2.0.2/resilience4j-timelimiter-2.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/3.1.3/spring-boot-starter-aop-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/6.0.11/spring-aop-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.20/aspectjweaver-1.9.20.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/3.1.3/spring-boot-starter-actuator-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/3.1.3/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/3.1.3/spring-boot-actuator-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-observation/1.11.3/micrometer-observation-1.11.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-commons/1.11.3/micrometer-commons-1.11.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.11.3/micrometer-core-1.11.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.12/HdrHistogram-2.1.12.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/latencyutils/LatencyUtils/2.0.3/LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/3.0.2/jakarta.validation-api-3.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/github/msarhan/ummalqura-calendar/2.0.2/ummalqura-calendar-2.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor/3.1.3/spring-boot-configuration-processor-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/3.1.3/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/3.1.3/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/5.0.1/HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/6.0.11/spring-jdbc-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.2.7.Final/hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/3.1.0/jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/transaction/jakarta.transaction-api/2.0.1/jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/6.0.6.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/jandex/3.0.5/jandex-3.0.5.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/classmate-1.5.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.14.6/byte-buddy-1.14.6.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/4.0.3/jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/4.0.3/jaxb-core-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/angus/angus-activation/2.0.1/angus-activation-2.0.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/4.0.3/txw2-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/4.1.2/istack-commons-runtime-4.1.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/inject/jakarta.inject-api/2.0.1/jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.10.1/antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/3.1.3/spring-data-jpa-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/3.1.3/spring-data-commons-3.1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/6.0.11/spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/6.0.11/spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/6.0.11/spring-aspects-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/21.9.0.0/ojdbc8-21.9.0.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-spatial/6.2.7.Final/hibernate-spatial-6.2.7.Final.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/geolatte/geolatte-geom/1.8.2/geolatte-geom-1.8.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/locationtech/jts/jts-core/1.18.2/jts-core-1.18.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.5.3.Final/jboss-logging-3.5.3.Final.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.28/lombok-1.18.28.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.0/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/2.1.2/jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/6.0.11/spring-core-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/6.0.11/spring-jcl-6.0.11.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar com.example.demo.DemoApplication
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50764', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.3)

2023-09-24T13:09:07.592+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.8 with PID 5615 (/Users/anish/Downloads/demo/target/classes started by anish in /Users/anish/Downloads/demo)
2023-09-24T13:09:07.595+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-09-24T13:09:08.785+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-09-24T13:09:08.859+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 57 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-09-24T13:09:09.224+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=fbabf9c4-2b1a-389f-80b2-693443647993
2023-09-24T13:09:10.046+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-09-24T13:09:10.057+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-09-24T13:09:10.058+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.12]
2023-09-24T13:09:10.189+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-09-24T13:09:10.190+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2530 ms
2023-09-24T13:09:10.785+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-09-24T13:09:10.858+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.7.Final
2023-09-24T13:09:10.860+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-09-24T13:09:10.871+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] o.h.spatial.integration.SpatialService   : HHH80000001: hibernate-spatial integration enabled : true
2023-09-24T13:09:11.047+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-09-24T13:09:11.469+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@3c7d8a4
2023-09-24T13:09:11.471+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-09-24T13:09:11.501+05:30  WARN 5615 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000026: Oracle12cDialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect instead
2023-09-24T13:09:11.695+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] org.hibernate.spatial                    : HHH80000003: hibernate-spatial adding type contributions from : org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleDialectContributor
2023-09-24T13:09:11.696+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] org.hibernate.spatial                    : HHH80000002: hibernate-spatial using Connection Finder for creating Oracle types : com.example.demo.CustomConnectionFinderForSpatialSupport
2023-09-24T13:09:11.725+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-09-24T13:09:11.908+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-09-24T13:09:11.939+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] org.hibernate.spatial                    : HHH80000003: hibernate-spatial adding type contributions from : org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleDialectContributor
2023-09-24T13:09:11.939+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] org.hibernate.spatial                    : HHH80000002: hibernate-spatial using Connection Finder for creating Oracle types : com.example.demo.CustomConnectionFinderForSpatialSupport
2023-09-24T13:09:12.121+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-09-24T13:09:12.229+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] org.hibernate.spatial                    : HHH80000004: hibernate-spatial adding function contributions from : org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleDialectContributor
2023-09-24T13:09:12.889+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-09-24T13:09:13.205+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-09-24T13:09:13.650+05:30  WARN 5615 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-09-24T13:09:14.837+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2023-09-24T13:09:14.938+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-09-24T13:09:14.973+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 7.939 seconds (process running for 8.645)
2023-09-24T13:15:29.478+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-09-24T13:15:29.481+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-09-24T13:15:29.506+05:30  INFO 5615 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 24 ms
MyGeo(id=ID, shape=POLYGON ((0 1, 2 5, 2 7, 0 7, 0 1)))
```

My DB updated with the data that I have sent:

[image]

That's all.

Comment: @sadegh Please ping me when you are available here.

Comment: @sadegh Is this helpful?

Comment: Thank you!  Just to clarify, my database is running on Oracle 19c, but I don't have APEX installed. I've followed your instructions closely, but I'm still encountering an error.

Comment: @sadegh  I was able to save the data with no issue. It's impossible to predict from here about what wrong you have done? Please check the table structure in DB, entity and controller. and try with Oracle 23c if possible. Can you remove the table and try again with my changes?

Comment: @sadegh Drop the existing table and let the spring-data jpa help to create your table.

Comment: @sadegh If you want I can share my codebase via github if possible. Will that help?

Comment: @sadegh Did you try by creating a fresh table?

Answer (score 0):

Try add in application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleSpatial10gDialect
```

Comment: project not run by this dialect, `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect.<init>(org.hibernate.dialect.DatabaseVersion)'`

Answer (score 0):

When mapping your `Entity` by `Hibernate` is not specified the spatial type for your `shape` field. So you need to make sure the `Polygon` is a type which is not adapted to use on `Geometry` points. So you use `Geometry` instead of `Polgon` and define your type so that Hibernate can match `org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryTpe` by doing the following code:

```
    @Column(name = "shape", columnDefinition = "MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    private Geometry shape;
```

The `Geometry` class, you can use from `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry`.

Comment: error: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType